# Lack of Yeast Fermenation

Tags: yeast, sugar, corn

During the fermentation my mash stopped bubbling after 5 days! Can yeast be added? I think I didn't put enough the first time!!

Comment: Bubbles aren't a great indicator of fermentation.  If you had 5 days of strong then you might be right on schedule.  What final gravity are you expecting and have you done any measurements?  Gravity is your best indicator.  And unless you're trying to turn it around quick, don't check until 2 weeks are up.

Comment: Should I just keep it in the carboy for 9 more days to distill??

Comment: It won't distill per say, but yeast and other bits will settle out to help the beer clarify.  Enough yeast will remain in suspension though to carbonate.  Another 9 days should be good if you had a strong initial ferment but the gravity measurements will tell you for sure if it's ready.

Comment: Please add more information.  What yeast did you use and what quantity?

Comment: I used Red Star Dady and I used 2 spoons, the clarity looks good and there is about 1 1/2 to 2 inches settled to the bottom of the 6 gal carboy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to tell if fermentation is done is by taking hydrometer readings. If the gravity numbers don't change over 2-3 days, it's done. Do you know what the target final gravity is? If fermentation is done and you're close on the final gravity, then no worries.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I assume you mean "wort" not mash  After 5 days it might very well be done fermenting.  What temperature did you ferment at?

Comment: the temp was from 74 - 78

Comment: OK, that's way too high, so it's no wonder it was done so quickly.  You will get much better quality beer if you can keep the temp between 65-70F.